# make iFrame resize based on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic, height

Is there any way of making the iframe refresh it's height after the content inside changes?

Example: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/forum/0-14

I'm using easyXDM

Page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/forum-external/xdm/easyXDM.js"></script>
<div id="page-body">
<!-- do not define an iframe, it will get generated for you in this container -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new easyXDM.Socket({
    remote: "http://thc-racing.forumotion.co.uk/",
    container: document.getElementById("page-body"),
    onMessage: function(message, origin){
        this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = message + "px";
        this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.width = "900px";
    }
});
</script>
```

iFramed page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/forum-external/xdm/easyXDM.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
onReady:  function() {
// this is needed for setting height on initial load
socket.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)
},
onMessage: function(message, origin){
// this is called from consumer (maybe by a timer)
socket.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)
}
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the iframe content from the same domain as the surrounding document? If so, you can simple access the parent page via `window.parent`, and access all its variables/functions – so the iframe would just have to measure its own document’s height, pass it over to the parent and that could then set the iframe elements height accordingly.

Comment: CBroe no it is not, it is cross-domain